# iOS App crashes when launched from local notification

Tags: ios, local, uilocalnotification

I have set up a daily reminder local notification for my app.  It works great when the app is in the background.  However, when the app is closed/not running, when the user taps LAUNCH in the notification, the app launches the main screen, then goes back to the home screen.

I have tried numerous code solutions on here, most involvingsomething along these lines:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        // handle your notification here.
    }
}
```

But no matter where I put this, the app launches but now turns to black.
Here is my code, can anyone help me figure out what to do here?
Please not, I am using Dreamweaver/phonegap to build the app.

```
//
//  assignmentAppDelegate.m
//  assignment
//
//  Created by Noel Chenier on 23 December, 2011.
//  Copyright  2011. All rights reserved.
//

#import "assignmentAppDelegate.h"
#import "PhoneGapViewController.h"

@implementation assignmentAppDelegate

- (id) init
{   
    /** If you need to do any extra app-specific initialization, you can do it here
     *  -jm
     **/
    return [super init];
}

/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here.
 */

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(UIApplication *)application
{   
{ 
     UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
}


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge  |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:@"enableNotifications"];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize];   
    [ super applicationDidFinishLaunching:application ];
}
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
}


-(id) getCommandInstance:(NSString*)className
{
    /** You can catch your own commands here, if you wanted to extend the gap: protocol, or add your
     *  own app specific protocol to it. -jm
     **/
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"enableNotifications"]) { 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calender components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)
                                                   fromDate:currentDate];

    NSDateComponents *temp = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

    [temp setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [temp setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [temp setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [temp setHour: 9];
    [temp setMinute:00];

    NSDate *fireTime = [calender dateFromComponents:temp];
    [temp release];

    // set up the notifier 
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    localNotification.fireDate = fireTime;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotification.alertBody = @"Don't Forget Your 365 Day Photo Challenge!";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"LAUNCH";

    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
}
else {[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];}
    return [super getCommandInstance:className];
}


/**
 Called when the webview finishes loading.  This stops the activity view and closes the imageview
 */
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    return [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    return [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
}

/**
 * Fail Loading With Error
 * Error - If the webpage failed to load display an error with the reson.
 */
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    return [ super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error ];
}

/**
 * Start Loading Request
 * This is where most of the magic happens... We take the request(s) and process the response.
 * From here we can re direct links and other protocalls to different internal methods.
 */
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}


- (BOOL) execute:(InvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    return [ super execute:command];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [ super dealloc ];
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you implemented this method : `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {`

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification is for foreGround and backGround.
Not for application start.

Comment: Noel ! I have exactlly the same problem.
And i am developing with xCode.
Have you found a proper solution yet ?
i can catch foreGround and backGround situations but not application launch situation.
Since debugger is not attached while appStart with notif, i do not know what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

For local notification,you need to add following things in  :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(UIApplication *)application
{ 
     UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. would I add that after the first code section i already have of (void)applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOption?
Noel

Comment: Yes,add in that existing method you have written,I was just explaining it.

Comment: when I plug that code i get "USE OF UNDECALRED IDENTIFIFER "launchOptions"

Comment: Can you please update your question with latest code you added that I suggested,so that I can have a look on it.

Comment: edited the code above to where it is now and getting the undeclared identifier

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out...

I'm not sure why it was crashing, but in the event anyone else having this problem comes across this, the notification will launch the app when your build for relase....it just doesnt appear to work when it's built/run for debug or another state.

So when you run, run for RELEASE and it should work just fine!